# IR: Specifying a carrier value with rc_keymap

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, configuration

I'm working on replacing remotes by using `ir-keytable` and `ir-ctl` commands, and `rc_keymap` TOML config files, as they have replaced lirc. I'm using Raspberry OS bullseye

One of my remotes use an unknown protocol, so I decided to store the raw signals.

I started by storing each button signal using `ir-ctl -rMY_KEY.txt --mode2 -r --device=/dev/lirc1 -1`
As I know the specific remote uses a carrier of 38kHz, I appended each signal by `carrier 38000` as explained in the man.

If I try to send the signal using `ir-ctl -sMY_KEY.txt`, it triggers the expected action.

Now, instead of having 1 file per button, I want to store the remote using a rc_keymap TOML file, as explained [here](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ir-keytable/rc_keymap.5.en.html)

Since I don't know the protocol, I use the `raw` one, so I used the command `ir-ctl --mode2 -r   --device=/dev/lirc1 -1` to retrieve each button's signal, then copy-pasted int my TOML file.

I now do `ir-ctl -kmy_remote.toml -KMY_kEY`. Nothing happens.
If I now do the same command, with a `--carrier 38000`, it does work, with the warning `warning: carrier specified but overwritten on command line`

My question is: Where is the carrier value is defined in a rc_keymap config file, and how can I override it? I see nothing about it in the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to read the C code of [`ir-ctl`](https://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git/tree/utils/ir-ctl) to take a guess, and found the answer. We can simply add a `carrier` field in he TOML file, to set this value.

So, this does work

```
[[protocols]]
name = "MY_REMOTE"
protocol = "raw"
carrier = 38000
```